How to extract arguments from call with ast python
I am working on a function to convert function calls, therefore I need the calls and parameters. I fiddled with AST, and I am able to extract the specific nodes, but somehow I can't distinguish the nodes by their type.
For example, I want to get the call and the parameters to do my make into a new syntax.
Example code:
import ast
import argparse

class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.arglist = []
    def visit(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            print('VVVVVVVVVVVVVV        CALL ANFANG            VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV')
            print(f'_______  Call found ______')
            super().visit(node)
            print(f'Argumente: >>>{node.args.pop(0).__dict__}<<<<')
            print('______________        CALL END              ________________')
        if isinstance(node, ast.Name):
            print(f'_______  Name found   ______   {node.__class__}')
            print(f'Name Argumente: {node.id.__str__()}')
            return super().visit(node)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.For):
            print(f'_______  FOR found  ______  ')
            return super().visit(node)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.keyword):
            print(f'_______  keyword found ______ {node.__class__}')
            return super().visit(node)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
            return super().visit(node)
            print(f'_______  Attribute fopund   _____   {node.__class__}')
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Expr):
            return super().visit(node)
            print(f'_______  Expr found ________   {node.__class__}')
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Constant):
            print(f'_______  Konstante found!!>>>>   {node.value}')
            return super().visit(node)

        return super().visit(node)



tree = ast.parse('''  
meat = get_mess(ONE, TWO, THREE)
name2 = 'Elise'
''')

print(ast.dump(tree))
vis = Visitor()
vis.visit(tree)

Output is:
Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='meat', ctx=Store())], value=Call(func=Name(id='get_mess', ctx=Load()), args=[Name(id='ONE', ctx=Load()), Name(id='TWO', ctx=Load()), Name(id='THREE', ctx=Load())], keywords=[])), Assign(targets=[Name(id='name2', ctx=Store())], value=Constant(value='Elise'))], type_ignores=[])
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: meat
VVVVVVVVVVVVVV        CALL ANFANG            VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
_______  Call found ______
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: get_mess
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: ONE
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: TWO
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: THREE
Argumente: >>>{'id': 'ONE', 'ctx': <ast.Load object at 0x7f42d71fca10>, 'lineno': 2, 'col_offset': 16, 'end_lineno': 2, 'end_col_offset': 19}<<<<
______________        CALL END              ________________
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: get_mess
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: TWO
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: THREE
_______  Name found   ______   <class 'ast.Name'>
Name Argumente: name2
_______  Konstante found!!>>>>   Elise

It is extracting function calls (get_mess) and parameters (ONE, TWO, THREE), but I didn't find a way to extract them by their type, so I can build new code.

What do you mean "by type"? There is no type information in the call itself. You would have to look at the values bound to each name, and that's not something available in the single node that represents the call.

I would like to access the function call and the parameters for that call

If you mean arguments, you have them. If you mean paramters, you need to find the definition of the function first. The AST node for the call only has the name.

Yes, it seems that ast is the wrong tool for me: i need something which gives me some sort of semantic preprocessing, for example extract all qualified python commandos with name and parameter, maybe i have to write it manually
